# Problems with Large DataTalbe in IE

Tags: internet-explorer, datatables

I´m using DataTables and it works well in Chrome and Forefox, but when it return large results of data it stpos working on IE.

Can you please help me with this.

Thanks,
Sílvia Gaspar

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest doing server side processing with large amounts of data. 
Server side 
http://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/server_side.html

Comment: I´m new on datatables. How can I use the server side processing in this cases?

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Bret.  Handle your data from server side and display data based on request instead of loading everything